# Set up drupal as a downloads site

Tags: drupal, download

I am new to drupal and was informed that it is a good cms to act as a downloads repository site, I have looked on google but can't find any tips on how to achieve this.

Is there a module I can use? Or?

Answer (score 0):

Check these modules, for a start, on drupal.org under Modules: Web File Manager, Storage API, Media Mover.